# How do I setup GRAV (a PHP application) on portable Apache?

Tags: windows, apache-http-server, php

I'm trying out some personal Wiki systems for my Windows 10 computer that uses plain Markdown files, and came across [GRAV](https://learn.getgrav.org/17/basics/what-is-grav). That is an Open Source CMS using Extract-and-drop setup most any web server having PHP 7 can run.

Since I've tried out DokuWiki before, I've already got [MicroApache](http://microapache.kerys.co.uk/installation.htm) available and thought I just needed to extract the GRAV-zip there. But it won't start, maybe I need a clean download and config of MicroApache?

```
C:.
+---grav
\---server
    +---conf
    +---logs
    +---modules
    \---php
        \---ext
```

I editied `.\server\conf\httpd.conf` to use the GRAV folder instead.

```
# absolute minimum configuration for DokuWiki on a Stick
# change the Listen directive if you want to use a different port

Listen 8800
ServerName microapache
ServerRoot .
DocumentRoot ./../grav
ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
```

But all I get when starting MicroApache is a broken webpage...

```
cd server
start "Apache server" /B mapache.exe
start http://localhost:8800/
```

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete 
your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@example.com to inform them of the 
time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

And there is no server to stop

```
ApacheKill.exe

■ Killing all matching processes
■ Searching for processes matching "mapache.exe"
Error: A process with that name does not appear to be running
```

Since most of the trouble shooting for GRAV is for Linux, I can't follow those guides on my Windows setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected, the distribution of DokuWikiStick was too heavily stripped to work.

I downloaded a clean version of Apache 2.4.54 from https://www.apachelounge.com/download/VC15/ and PHP8 Thread Safe (as required by Apache for Windows) from https://windows.php.net/download/

```
.
+---Apache24
+---grav
\---php8
```

In PHP I renamed `php.ini-development` to `php.ini`.

Then I adjusted Apache `httpd.conf` to use relative paths, use PHP8 and startup with GRAV.

```
Define SRVROOT "."

ServerName apache

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html
LoadModule php_module "./../php8/php8apache2_4.dll"
PHPiniDir "./../php8"

DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/../grav"
<Directory "${SRVROOT}/../grav">

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>
```

Then I could access GRAV PHP-application, using my web browser, which told me what additional configurations and setups I was missing.

Comment: Turns out that the PHP-code for GRAV had it's own web server. No, need to use Apache.